# He was shocked into a confession of guilt. (What kind of 'shock' is implied here?)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> He was shocked into a confession of guilt.

In what context, does the sentence above can be used?

Comment: In a dictatorship or police state, maybe an electric shock, but otherwise, the normal meaning of 'shock' in a dictionary.

Comment: It could be any kind of shock. There's nothing that restricts the meaning of *shock* in that sentence.

Comment: Better: He was shocked [electric??] into "confessing" his guilt. As Michael says, in a police state.

Comment: "In what context **can the sentence be used**?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the subject makes a confession as the result of something unexpected (which could be verbal or physical).

"Having been accused of an affair he was shocked into a confession of guilt when his wife slapped him."

"After being informed that they had found the murder weapon, which he believed to have been permanently disposed of, he was shocked into a confession of guilt."